# React.js - how to create Accordeon (talking to siblings)

Tags: javascript, accordion, reactjs

I just started using react.js and i love the way components work. I created a `Card` component, which will add a css-class `expanded` on click. This works like a charm. Now I want all the other cards to loose there `expanded` property once another card is clicked. In jQuery i'd use `siblings` to do this.

What is the proper solution with react.js?

Here's my code:

```
var Card = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            expanded: false,
            //clickCount: 0
        };
    },

    handleClick: function (event) {
        this.setProps({expanded: !this.props.expanded});
    },

    render: function () {
        var cx = React.addons.classSet;
        var classes = cx({
            'card': true,
            'expanded': this.state.expanded
        });

        return (
            <li className={classes} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.entf.toFixed(2)} km</h2>
            </li>
        )
    }

});


var App = React.createClass({

    handleClick: function (event) {
        console.log("clicked");
    },

    render: function () {

        var pools = this.props.data.map(function (pool) {
            return (
                <Card onClick={this.handleClick} name={pool.name} entf={pool.entf} />
            );
        });

        return (<ul>
                {pools}
        </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a heads up, classSet is being deprecated so you might want to switch to [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) when you have a minute (the api is 100% compatible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `siblings`, you should keep an identifier to the expanded card in the `App` component's `state` and let React re-render if the selected card changes.

Here is an example how you would do it with react:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vdw27xpf/

```
var Card = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        var cx = React.addons.classSet;
        var classes = cx({
            'card': true,
            'expanded': this.props.expanded
        });

        return (
            <li className={classes} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.entf.toFixed(2)} km</h2>
            </li>
        )
    }

});


var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState : function(){
        return { expandedCardName : null };
    },

    handleClick: function (value) {
       this.setState({ expandedCardName : value });
    },

    render: function () {

        var pools = this.props.data.map(function (pool) {
            return (
                <Card key={pool.name}
                      expanded = { pool.name == this.state.expandedCardName }
                      onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,pool.name)} 
                      name={pool.name} entf={pool.entf} />
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (<ul>
                {pools}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
var data = [ { name:"card1", entf:60 },{ name:"card2", entf:50 } ]; 
React.render(<App data={data} />, document.body);
```

Comment: You solution works, while the one of @Miles above does not. His solution misses the "final" .bind(this) on the map function. Could you explain what this "bind" does?

Comment: `bind` creates a new function with context ( the value of `this` ) equal to its first parameter. The parameters after the first one, will be parameters to the function when called. for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: With @Miles answer `this` will not point to React Components context inside `map` function. Hence `this.handleClick` and `this.state` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. I got my head around it now. I'd have proposal to make the code even more understandable, for new users like me. In the line 
`onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,pool.name)}`
The `onClick` is not a real onClick-Event but a props to be handed down to the  `<Card>` Component. It took me some time to realize this, as they are called the same. Wouldn't it be better to call the props-onClick sth else, like clickHandler, or am i over-thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't React super?

To get the behaviour you want without too much modification, I suggest passing a callback `onClick` or `onExpand` to each `<Card/>`. When a Card is activated, it runs the callback which can set a variable (perhaps `activeCard`) in App's state. In App's render method, modify the map function to give each Card an `expanded` boolean prop, which will be true depending on if the card's name/id matches `activeCard`. Use the new `expanded` prop instead of `this.state.expanded` in each Card's logic.

```
var Card = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    var cx = React.addons.classSet;
    var classes = cx({
        'card': true,
        'expanded': this.props.expanded
    });

    return (
        <li className={classes} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <h2>{this.props.entf.toFixed(2)} km</h2>
        </li>
    )
}

});


var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
    return { activeCard: '' }
},

render: function () {

    var pools = this.props.data.map(function (pool) {
        return (
            <Card onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,pool.name)} name={pool.name} entf={pool.entf} expanded={pool.name == this.state.activeCard} />
        );
    }.bind(this));

    return (<ul>
            {pools}
    </ul>
    )
},

handleClick: function (value) {
    this.setState({ activeCard: value })
}
});
```

When working in React, think about how to keep components as stateless as possible. In paradigms like jQuery these pieces often manage themselves, but if you want to use React's potential then always keep an eye out for how to 'trickle' down state.

Comment: Tanks a lot for the explanation. Your code does not work though, it misses a "bind(this)" appended to the map function (taken from the code of @nilgun). Than it works like a charm.

Comment: @leosok Hawhoops. Next time I'll edit this in Sublime. Fixed in the answer though. I just lost where I was in the code.